# how to add custom item to last index on listView reverse mode?

Tags: flutter, dart

my listview is the reverse order. I want to add a custom item to the last index on listView reverse mode? (to first item)

```
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length + 1,
          reverse: true,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            if (index == snapshot.data.length -1) {
              return Container(
                  child: myEnquiry());
            }
              index -= 1;

            return other_widget();

         }
     );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.length + 1,
  reverse: true,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    if (index == 0) {   // Fix this line.
      return Container(child: myEnquiry());
    }
    index -= 1;

    return other_widget();

  },
);
```

[image]

or

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.length + 1,
  reverse: true,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    if (index == snapshot.data.length) {   // Fix this line.
      return Container(child: myEnquiry());
    }
//    index -= 1;   // Fix this line.

    return other_widget();

  },
);
```

[image]